# PHP: populated fields and database insert

Tags: php, mysql

i have Form what populate fields from database, can you show me php to insert data to database, each score to own row in database (id,name,score)

Updated: whit theis codes it prints like this:

> lines updated to database:  7 - James - 15
>
> lines updated to database:  7 - James - 15
>
> lines updated to database:  7 - James - 15

**now i use this form:**

```
<form action="insert_action2.php" id="form2" title="form2" method="post">
<table>
<?php

        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "form", "form", "form");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 



$sql = "SELECT * FROM form2" ;
$players = $link->query($sql);
        while($player = $players->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>

          <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $player["id"]; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $player["name"]; ?>">

            </td>
            <td>    
                <input type="text" name="score" id="score" size="2" value="<?php echo $player["score"]; ?>">
            </td>   
        </p>
        <?php
        } 
        $link->close();
        ?>

    </tr>
    </table>
        <input type="submit" value="update scores">
</form>
```

**insert to database -insert_action2.php**
i have tried couple arrays and foreach but cant get those working right...

```
<?php

foreach($_POST as $players => $value) {

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
$score = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['score']);

    $sql = "UPDATE form2 SET score='$score', name='$name' WHERE id=$id";        
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                echo "lines updated to database: <br>$id - $name - $score <br><br><p><p>";
            } else{
                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
}

mysqli_close($link);


?>
```

Comment: Really?, did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: is your form using method POST?

Comment: @storm5 it looks you the user will submit multiple scores to you. In that case, you need to add`[]` to the end of the name attributes of the id,name, and score inputs. `<input type="text" name="score[]"...` like that

Comment: have you executed your query??

Comment: Are you sure you want to insert a new record based on the form input? To me it seems that you rather want to update them.

Comment: "i have tried couple arrays" — I don't see them in your code.  "and foreach" — ditto.

Comment: i updated sources to starting post.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use:

```
$sql = "insert into `form2`(`name`, `score`) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$score}')";
```

When you use some variable inside a string, you need to scape the variable.

Or use this way:

```
$sql = "insert into `form2`(`name`, `score`) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $score . "')";
```

Comment: That's not true. You only need to do that when the variable is a more complicated expression (e.g. property of an object) or when the character following it in the string is one that is allowed in a variable name.